# Opaque struct with C linkage & C++ implementation

Tags: c++, c, linker

Say I want a struct `foo` with C linkage. I'll declare it in a C-style header file (foo.h) opaquely:

```
struct foo;
typedef struct foo foo;
```

But I want to use C++ in the implementation of `foo`. Say I want `foo` to contain a `std::vector<int>`. Since C code wouldn't have access to `foo`'s fields, I don't see why the compiler (or language standards) should prohibit this. But how would I do that? Can I just put `extern "C"` around the implementation of `foo` in foo.cc like this?

```
extern "C" {
    struct foo {
        ....
        std::vector<int> bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Structs don't have linkage

Comment: ... nor does `extern "C"` make your code compile as C.

Comment: To state the same thing in a constructive manner, what `extern "C"` *does* is to make all functions declared or defined within its scope (a) use C naming conventions, and (b) use C calling conventions.  But in all other ways, it's still C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up stuffing C++ under C a lot...here's the general gist of it.  (And as an aside, letting C++ exceptions unwind the C stack can cause issues for the C code that is unaware such things can happen...so it's advisable to do some `catch(...)` blocks in the C++ interface functions.)

**lib.h**: A header file that declares a few functions with C calling convention no matter whether it's compiled as C or C++

```
#pragma once

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Looks like a typical C library interface */

struct c_class;

struct c_class *do_init();
void do_add(struct c_class *tgt, int a);
int  do_get_size(const struct c_class *tgt);
void do_cleanup(struct c_class *tgt);


#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

**lib.cpp**: A C++ library with a few functions declared with C calling convention

```
#include "lib.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

class Foo
{
  std::vector<int> m_vec;
public:
  Foo() : m_vec() {}
  virtual ~Foo() {}

  void add(int a) {
    m_vec.push_back(a);
  }

  int getSize() {
    return m_vec.size();
  }
};


/* Exposed C interface with C++ insides */
extern "C" {

  struct c_class
  {
    Foo *guts;
  };

  struct c_class *do_init()
  {
    struct c_class *obj = static_cast<c_class*>(malloc(sizeof(struct c_class)));
    obj->guts = new Foo();
    return obj;
  }

  void do_add(struct c_class *tgt, int a) {
    tgt->guts->add(a);
  }

  int do_get_size(const struct c_class *tgt) {
    return tgt->guts->getSize();
  }

  void do_cleanup(struct c_class *tgt) {
    delete tgt->guts;
    free(tgt);
  }
}
```

**main.c**: A C program that uses the C calling convention functions exported from lib

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  struct c_class *obj;

  obj = do_init();

  for(i = 0; i< 100; i++)
  {
    do_add(obj, i);
  }

  printf("Size: %d\n", do_get_size(obj));

  do_cleanup(obj);
}
```

**Makefile**: a makefile that builds the C as C, and the C++ as C++, then uses the C++ compiler to do the link

```
CXXFLAGS ?= -Wall -Werror -pedantic
CFLAGS ?= -Wall -Werror -pedantic

.PHONY: all
all : test

test: lib.o main.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test lib.o main.o

lib.o: lib.cpp lib.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

main.o: main.c lib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm lib.o main.o test
```

**Output**:

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c lib.cpp -o lib.o
cc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c main.c -o main.o
g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o test lib.o main.o

$ ./test
Size: 100
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the virtual keyword from the destructor? Your class can't have a vtable if you want to be compatible with C.

Comment: @MaxRahm...I don't understand your question.  It works just fine with the vtable in Foo, because the struct only has a pointer to Foo.  (It would've held the Foo object via a `void *` if the struct wasn't opaque to C).  The OP asked for an opaque struct that could hold STL, not a method for making C++ objects that are compatible w/ C.  This is literally a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

A struct is compatible between C and C++ as long as the content of the struct is POD (plain old data). If you add non-POD into it e.g. your vector, it no longer is compatible with C and will cause undefined behavior when used with typical C functions like `memset` or `memcpy`. The non-POD members cause another memory layout of the struct, it gets a virtual table at the start of it to support inheritance.

Comment: But if all C sees is an opaque struct, surely compatibility of members is irrelevant?

Comment: not if the members have constructors/virtual tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Struct by itself is just a type, in other words a syntactic sugar which does not exist beyond compilation as a struct, but just as several bytes in memory and pointers to it. Therefore it does not have any language specific linkage. Meaning of bytes is defined by the compiler at compilation time and references to them are created also there. So, its layout depends on the language you use.

Answering your question, the std::vector implementation contains certain fields which become a part of the struct layout. c++ understands them, since it understands templates and all other object-oriented stuff, 'c' will choke on the template in the first place as well as other c++sness. So, struct definitions are not compatible if you use non POD data.

If you use POD, standard 'c' data types, no member functions and no bit fields, you should be all set and compatible in definition. Which means that both compilers will compile the struct and the layout will be similar, so that you can save/restore it cross languages.

If you are talking about just passing the pointers to a c++ struct through a 'c' code, than you should be all set in any case. you can use cast to 'void*' to do so in a standard way.